# Google Chrome: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I keep on getting this error on chromium but not on Firefox n its driving me nuts because I cant find a solution despite searching for hours now. I basically get JSON from the server and then wanna insert it into DOM. Here's my code...

```
function lookup(inputString){
    if(inputString.length == 0){        //hide suggestions
        $('#suggestions').empty()
                 .fadeOut();
         }
    else{           //make an AJAX call
         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{% url "search.views.search" inputString="xyz" %}'.replace("xyz", inputString.toString()),
            dataType: 'json',
                success: function(search_results){
            suggestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(search_results));
                        alert(suggestions[0].name);

                    }
                })
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `;` at the end of this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{% url "search.views.search" inputString="xyz" %}'.replace("xyz", inputString.toString()),
            dataType: 'json',
                success: function(search_results){
            suggestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(search_results));
                        alert(suggestions[0].name);

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Why wouldn't JavaScript's ASI handle that situation?

Comment: @ElliotM: Not exactly sure why, but I guess Chromium is stricter than Firefox on this rule, at least for this particular function call. I've seen Chrome (not Chromium) do ASI in some situations. But no harm doing the syntax correctly yourself, rather than risk the browser tripping up like this.

Comment: Thanks for that but my code seems to have an error that i can't find. The AJAX call is not made for every letter i input, which i am finding annoying. I may type 's' and the alert will pop up but when i type 'i', nothing :-(

Answer (score 0):

same conclusion :)

you missed a semicolon `;`

jslint could help you to find this kind of errors : http://www.jslint.com/

```
function lookup(inputString) {
  if (inputString.length === 0) {
    $('#suggestions').empty().fadeOut();
  }
  else {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '{% url "search.views.search" inputString="xyz" %}'.replace("xyz", inputString.toString()),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(search_results) {
        suggestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(search_results));
        alert(suggestions[0].name);
      }
    });
  }
}
```